# Product rule of distribution by multiplicating a $C^\infty$ function

Tags: partial-differential-equations, distribution-theory

I am reading S. Kesavan's book "Topics In Functional Analysis and Application" and trying to prove the product rule, can you check where I am going wrong?

Let $\psi \in C^\infty (\mathbb{R})$ and $T \in \mathcal{D}'(\mathbb{R})$ , and $\phi \in \mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R})$.

then,

$\begin{align} \dfrac{d}{dx} (\psi T)(\phi) = - \psi T \Big( \dfrac{d\phi}{dx}  \Big) = -T \Big( \psi \dfrac{d\phi}{dx} \Big) = -T \Big( \dfrac{d}{dx} (\psi \phi) \Big) + T \left( \dfrac{d\psi}{dx}\phi  \right) 
\end{align}$

by the chain rule of differentiation and linearity of $T$.

Now, can you check the following part where am I going wrong?

$-T \Big( \dfrac{d}{dx} (\psi \phi) \Big) = \dfrac{d}{dx} \Big( T(\psi \phi) \Big) = \dfrac{d}{dx} \Big( \psi T( \phi) \Big)  =  \psi \dfrac{d}{dx} T(\phi) + \dfrac{d\psi}{dx} T(\phi)$

And, $T \Big( \dfrac{d\psi}{dx}\phi  \Big) = \dfrac{d\psi}{dx} T(\phi)$

But the answer in total should be : $ \dfrac{d}{dx} (\psi T)(\phi) = \psi \dfrac{d}{dx} T(\phi) + \dfrac{d\psi}{dx} T(\phi) $

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer : $\frac{\text d}{\text d x} \Big( T(\psi\phi) \Big)$ makes no sense.

Long answer : You have :
\begin{align}
- T\left(\frac{d}{dx} (\psi\phi)\right) &= \left(\frac{dT}{dx}\right)(\psi\phi) \\
&= \left( \psi \frac{dT}{dx}\right)(\phi)\\
\end{align}

and :
$$T\left(\frac{d\psi}{dx}\phi\right) = \left( \frac{d\psi}{dx}T\right)(\phi)$$

Which gives the right product rule
$$\left( \frac{d}{dx}(\psi T)\right)(\phi) =  \left( \psi \frac{dT}{dx}\right)(\phi) + \left( \frac{d\psi}{dx}T\right)(\phi)$$

**Notation advice** : to avoid such mistakes, I recommend using the following notation :
$$\langle T,\phi\rangle \overset{\text{def}}{=} T(\phi)$$

Then, the derivation of the product rule is :
\begin{align}
\left\langle \frac{d}{dx}(\psi T), \phi \right\rangle &= - \left\langle \psi T , \frac{d}{dx} \phi \right\rangle \\
&= - \left\langle T, \psi \frac{d\phi}{dx} \right\rangle \\
&= \left\langle T, \frac{d\psi}{dx} \phi - \frac{d}{dx}(\phi\psi) \right\rangle \\
&= \left\langle \frac{d\psi}{dx}  T ,\phi\right\rangle + \left\langle \frac{dT}{dx}, \phi\psi\right\rangle\\
&= \left\langle \frac{d\psi}{dx}  T + \psi \frac{dT}{dx},\phi \right\rangle
\end{align}

Comment: hey, thanks a lot :)

Comment: but i am just starting to read distribution and not clear why " $d/dx(T(\psi \phi))$ makes no sense." can you please explain? $\psi \phi \in \mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R}) $ right?

Comment: $\psi\phi \in \mathcal D(\mathbb R)$ so $T(\psi\phi) \in\mathbb R$ and you cannot the derivative. With the bracket notation, you are writing $d/dx \langle T,\psi\phi\rangle$. The correct equality is $\langle T, d/dx(\phi\psi)\rangle = -\langle dT/dx,\phi\psi\rangle$

Comment: ah right we need an operator not something in $\mathbb{R}$. so how exactly does this derivative operator work here? $T$ is acting on $\phi$ and the derivative operator is finding "something/some operator" which is derivative of $T$. what is this operator exactly? is the derivative we get is another operator in $\mathcal{D}'(\mathbb{R})$ bcs $T$ is smooth so we expect the derivative to be smooth? i have seen such things before, like "differentials" (if am not wrong) which take an operator on a space (at some point in $\mathbb{R^n}$ ) and find some other operator

Answer (score 0):

Note that:

$\begin{align} \dfrac{d}{dx} (\psi T)(\phi) &= -T \Big( \psi \dfrac{d\phi}{dx} \Big) = -T \Big( \dfrac{d}{dx} (\psi \phi) \Big) + T \left( \dfrac{d\psi}{dx}\phi  \right) \\
&=\left\langle\frac{dT}{dx}, \psi \phi \right\rangle+\left\langle\frac{d\psi}{dx}T, \phi \right\rangle\\
&=\left\langle\frac{dT}{dx}\psi,  \phi \right\rangle+\left\langle\frac{d\psi}{dx}T, \phi \right\rangle.
\end{align}$